# Is it possible to get R to identify countries in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, nlp, columnsorting

This is what my dataset currently looks like. I'm hoping to add a column with the country names that correspond with the 'paragraph' column, but I don't even know how to start going about with that. Should I upload a list of all country names and then use the match function?

Any suggestions for a more optimal way would be appreciated! Thank you.

[image: my current dataset]

The output of dput(head(dataset, 20)) is as follows:

```
structure(list(category = c("State Ownership and Privatization;...row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think using a list of countries and matching is probably the best.  Even from the short snipped you've got here, you can't rely on identifying proper nouns that are not at the start of the sentence.  There is an R package called `countrycode` that has lots of lists of countries in it, use `countrycode::codelist` to see it.

Comment: I agre with @DaveArmstrong but use `grep`, not `match`. Can you post the output of `dput(head(dataset, 20))` in the question?

Comment: And be careful of countries that have nested names. You'll want to look for matches for "South Sudan" before "Sudan", "Dominican Republic" before "Dominica", "Guinea-Bissau", "Papua New Guinea" and "Equatorial Guinea" before "Guinea", etc. Or maybe you could do something where if there are multiple matches you use the pattern with the most characters.

Comment: Also make sure how you define what should match, consider "The representative of Albania confirmed the invitation for a pizza party on the Australian beach with representatives of Belgium and their Dutch colleagues." What you want as outcome?

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg That's a good point, thanks. How would I go about defining what should match if I want "Albania" in this case? Would grep suffice?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Added!

Comment: No, that's not a data example, the data is missing! I was talking about the full output of the instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package "countrycode":

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(entry_number = 1:5,
                 text = c("a few paragraphs that might contain the country name congo or democratic republic of congo",
                          "More text that might contain myanmar or burma, as well as thailand",
                          "sentences that do not contain a country name can be returned as NA",
                          "some variant of U.S or the united states",
                          "something with an accent samóoa"))
```

This is how you can match the country names in a separate column:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#install.packages("countrycode")
library(countrycode)
all_country <- countryname_dict %>% 
  # filter out non-ASCII country names:
  filter(grepl('[A-Za-z]', country.name.alt)) %>%
  # define column `country.name.alt` as an atomic vector:
  pull(country.name.alt) %>% 
  # change to lower-case:
  tolower()

# define alternation pattern of all country names:
library(stringr)
pattern <- str_c(all_country, collapse = '|')  # A huge alternation pattern!

df %>%
  # extract country name matches
  mutate(country = str_extract_all(tolower(text), pattern))
  entry_number                                                                                       text
1            1 a few paragraphs that might contain the country name congo or democratic republic of congo
2            2                         More text that might contain myanmar or burma, as well as thailand
3            3                         sentences that do not contain a country name can be returned as NA
4            4                                                   some variant of U.S or the united states
5            5                                                            something with an accent samóoa
                              country
1 congo, democratic republic of congo
2             myanma, burma, thailand
3                                    
4                       united states
5                              samóoa
```